# Notify Unity about modified values in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, reflection

I am writing a custom inspector to solve the problems I have with Unity's default inspector. My system uses reflection and attributes to draw customizable inspectors. **Modifying instances without entering playmode works fine.** The problem is, that the editor doesn't seem to see the changes I make to my objects. This can be observed the usual way:

- Instances reset on play.
- Instances reset on editor reopen.

My editor takes about a second to save a scene and the cursor changes during that time. This can be triggered by saving the scene after changing some values in any `MonoBehaviour` (f.e. `RigidBody`).

Using my own inspector and modifying values followed by saving the scene won't trigger the actual saving process (no visual clues). **As if Unity believes there were no changes.**

The GameObject I'd like to modify in the inspector:

```
[EnableIR]
public class CustomerSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Inspect(InspectionKind.DropableObject)]
    public GameObject CustomerPrefab; // This field resets to null on play.
}
```

I use `PropertyInfo.SetValue` or `FieldInfo.SetValue` to modify values and references using Reflection. **Is there some method we need to call to notify Unity about changes?**

Links:

- [My GitHub Repository](https://github.com/NoelWidmer/unity3d-inspector-reflector) containing my custom inspector.
- [This class in my Repository](https://github.com/NoelWidmer/unity3d-inspector-reflector/blob/master/Assets/IRDrawer.cs) contains the code  that actually sets the value. (Search for `SetValue`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself and I believe the solution deserves more presence in the web than it currently has (which is basically none). One solution is to call `EditorUtility.SetDirty` in order to inform Unity that the insance has been modified:

```
// `target` is the object you are currently inspecting. 
EditorUtility.SetDirty((UnityEngine.Object)target);
```

As mentioned in the comments by [@Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer) `EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty` should be used instead. This is also mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html), but they don't provide a reason or explanation.

Comment: It's weird. [The docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html) describe `EditorUtility.SetDirty` to do something differently and inform the reader to use `Undo.RecordObject` from 5.3 onward. `Undo.RecordObject` doesn't do anything for me though. All expert experience much appreciated. :-)

Comment: You need to use `EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty` instead. Try that and see what happens. Just pass the current scene to it.

Comment: @Programmer That seems to work as well and is probably the better thing to do.